# Keep an ellipse round on all zoom levels

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm attempting to draw circles around X/Y coordinates. I'm attempting to keep the X axis size of the ellipse constant on all scaling/zoom levels and the Y axis variable in order to keep the ellipse circular at all times. As I understand, I would need to compare the QPicture `boundingRect()` to the displayed object rect as a ratio but I'm not certain how to achieve this.

For example, here the ellipse looks roughly circular, roughly desired outcome:

[image]

Zoomed out, the ellipse becomes oblong as the Y axis has changed. Desired outcome would be to see a circle shaped ellipse (vertical size reduced):

[image]

The function drawing the chart values and ellipses:

```
def candlesticks(self):
    self.picture = QPicture()
    painter = QPainter(self.picture)
    painter.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))

    for t, (open, high, low, close, entry, exit) in enumerate(self.data, start = Main.vr_start + 1):
        if open > close:
            painter.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
        else:
            painter.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))

        if high != low:
            painter.drawLine(QPointF(t, low), QPointF(t, high))
            painter.drawRect(QRectF(t - self.width, open, self.width * 2, close - open))
        else:
            painter.drawLine(QPointF(t - self.width, close), QPointF(t + self.width, close))

        painter.setBrush(pg.mkBrush(200, 200, 200, 0))
        if not np.isnan(entry):
            painter.drawEllipse(QRectF(t - self.width * 1.5, entry, self.width * 3, 0.1))

    painter.end()
```

Comment: Where are you drawing those QPictures? Is `candlesticks` recalled everytime the graph zoom/ratio changes? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I will try to post a MRE later (the project itself is large). Candlesticks is in a pyqtgraph GraphicsObject class, it's called once at chart creation and then redrawn when either zoom level changes or buffer is consumed to the end (simply for performance reasons).

Comment: Mmh, then I frankly doubt it will work. QPicture only stores *static* QPainter operations, but in your case you need to work with dynamic properties (most importantly, the current transformation, which can only be retrieved from the *active* actual QPainter, not that used for their creation). For normal situations, using the flag `ItemIgnoresTransformations` on the QGraphicsItem that draws the object could be fine, but the problem here is not the aspect ratio or rotation, but scaling (which itself is a transformation).